# Why I am getting quicksort.exe has stopped working and error 255 <0xff> while running my code of quicksort algorithm?I am using Code Blocks

Tags: c, data-structures, quicksort

I am running this code on Code Blocks and getting error as `quicksort.exe` has stopped working. The main function works fine. What is the reason? How can I solve this issue?

### **The code is as following:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quicksort(int *,int,int);
int part(int *,int,int);

int main()
{
    int i,n, a[100];
    printf("Enter the length of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter array elements\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    quicksort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("\nSorted array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
}


void quicksort(int *a,int lb,int ub)
{
    int p;

    if(lb>ub)
        return;

    p= part(a,lb,ub);
    quicksort(a,lb,p-1);
    quicksort(a,p+1,ub);
    return;
 }

int part(int *x, int l, int u)
{

    int piv,i,t,t2,pos=l;
    piv=x[u];

    for(i=l;i<=u;i++)
    {
        if(x[i]<=piv)
        {
            t=x[i];
            x[i]=x[pos];
            x[pos]=t;
            pos++;
        }

    }
    t2=x[pos];
    x[pos]=x[u];
    x[u]=t2;
    return pos;
}
```

While all other sorting algorithms are working fine. I am getting problem in mergesort and quick sort.

Is the problem with recursion or pointers?

Comment: Why is there c++ tag

Comment: What you have is a *crash*. You use a *debugger* to locate where it happens in your code. When in the debugger, after catching the crash and locating where in your code it happens, you can then examine involved variables and their values to make sure they seem valid. If you still can't solve it, then edit your question to give us these details (location and variable values).

Comment: `t2=x[pos];` : `x[pos]` might occurs out of bounds.

Comment: your code is using too much memory. I tried running few times with unsuccessful attempts and it is making my machine (Ubuntu 16.04) freeze.
I debugged it with gdb and got a segmentation fault during starting of part() function at line 36.
Backtrace is giving a lots of logs.
The BT is full with this line:
`#26271 0x00000000004007a2 in quicksort (a=0x7fffffffdbc0, lb=0, ub=0) at quick.c:30
        p = 1
#26272 0x00000000004007a2 in quicksort (a=0x7fffffffdbc0, lb=0, ub=0) at quick.c:30`

Comment: I suspect that if the lower bound equals the upper bound you get stuck in infinite recursion. A quick code inspection suggests that will be case.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code by this(There are two codes closest to your idea, I add annotate):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quicksort(int *,int,int);
int part(int *,int,int);

int main()
{
    int i,n, a[100];
    printf("Enter the length of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter array elements\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    quicksort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("\nSorted array:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
}


void quicksort(int *a,int lb,int ub)
{
    int p;

    if(lb>ub)
        return;

    p= part(a,lb,ub);
    quicksort(a,lb,p-1);
    quicksort(a,p+1,ub);
    return;
}

int part(int *x, int l, int u)
{

    int piv,i,t,pos=l-1;  //not pos = l 
    piv=x[u];

    for(i=l;i<=u;i++) // You can write:for(i = l; i < u; i++)
    {
        if(x[i]<=piv)
        {
            pos++;    //pos should add 1 before swap
            t=x[i];
            x[i]=x[pos];
            x[pos]=t;
        }

    }
    //If you write for(i = l; i < u; i++), use the following three lines of code
    //t2=x[pos+1]; 
    //x[pos+1]=x[u];
    //x[u]=t2;
    return pos;
}
```

I think the reason your code crashes is if you use `pos = l` and write `pos++` after swap , `x[pos]` might occurs out of bounds.But even if you modify it, there are other errors.Maybe you shoule draw a picture to understand quick sort and learn more details.